# Getting an wrong answer in scheme program

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, newtons-method

I am trying to find the cube root of a number using Newton's method. I wrote scheme procedures as follows:

```lisp
(define (cbrt x)
    (cbrt-iter 1.0 x))

(define (cbrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x) guess (cbrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))

(define (good-enough? guess x)
    (< (- guess (improve guess x)) 0.00001))

(define (improve guess x)
    (/ (+ (/ x (* guess guess)) (* 2 guess)) 3))

(cbrt 27)
(cbrt 8)
(cbrt 64)
```

Actually I am working on Exercise 1.8 of the famous (or may be infamous) book SICP. then I run `scheme < cuberoot.scm` and got the following result:

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2019 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Thursday September 5, 2019 at 11:51:46 AM
  Release 10.1.10 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118

1 ]=> (define (cbrt x)
    (cbrt-iter 1.0 x))
;Value: cbrt

1 ]=> (define (cbrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x) guess (cbrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))
;Value: cbrt-iter

1 ]=> (define (good-enough? guess x)
    (< (- guess (improve guess x)) 0.00001))
;Value: good-enough?

1 ]=> (define (improve guess x)
    (/ (+ (/ x (* guess guess)) (* 2 guess)) 3))
;Value: improve

1 ]=> (cbrt 27)
;Value: 1.

1 ]=> (cbrt 8)
;Value: 1.

1 ]=> (cbrt 64)
;Value: 1.

1 ]=> 
End of input stream reached.
Post proelium, praemium.
```

The program is always producing 1. as a result. I also tried adjusting the threshold value in `good-enough?` procedure from 0.00001 to 0.0001 and so on but that didn't worked.
Please explain what went wrong and how to fix that.

Comment: Try debugging in smaller pieces. You know `guess` starts at 1, so see what `(improve 1 27)` is. Is it what you expect? If not, work on the improvement formula. If so, check into what uses the result of `(improve 1 27)`. What will `(good-enough? 1 27)` yield? Is that what you expect? et cetera

Comment: Your program's structure calls for each iteration to wastefully call `improve` twice with the same values.  You want something like `(let ((imp (improve guess x))) (if (good-enough imp guess x) imp (cbrt-iter imp x)))`.   Here `good-enough` takes the improved value as an argument and so doesn't have to call `improve` to calculate it.

Comment: An alternative is to change the polarity of `good-enough` and call it `needs-improvement`.  This function returns the improved guess if the current guess isn't good enough, otherwise the false value `#f`.   Then you can do `(let ((imp (needs-improvement? guess x))) (if imp (cbrt-iter imp x) guess))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include an `(abs ...)` in `good-enough?`, otherwise you don't just see if two values are close enough, but just if one value is greater than another (approximately).

```lisp
(define (good-enough? guess x)
  (< (abs (- guess (improve guess x))) 0.00001))
```

Answer (score 1):

MIT-SCHEME can help you, see [Tracing Procedures in MIT-Scheme](https://cs.wellesley.edu/%7Ecs251/s00/trace.html). Tracing is a way for the interpreter to indicate what expression currently being computed, and what result it yields. After having entered your definitions, you can trace your procedures as follows:

```
(trace cbrt-iter)
(trace good-enough?)
(trace improve)
(trace cbrt)
```

Here is the interaction with input 64:

```
1 ]=> (cbrt 64)

[Entering #[compound-procedure 15 cbrt]
    Args: 64]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 12 cbrt-iter]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 13 good-enough?]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[Entering #[compound-procedure 14 improve]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[22.
      <== #[compound-procedure 14 improve]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[#t
      <== #[compound-procedure 13 good-enough?]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[1.
      <== #[compound-procedure 12 cbrt-iter]
    Args: 1.
          64]
[1.
      <== #[compound-procedure 15 cbrt]
    Args: 64]
;Value: 1.
```

Each time you call a traced procedure, you see:

```
[Entering ...]
```

Each time that procedure exits, its value is printed:

```
[XYZ
      <== <CALL THAT PRODUCED THE VALUE>]
```

Here, you can see that `(improve 1. 64)` returned 22, and that 22 is a good-enough value, from the result of `(good-enough? 1. 64)`. Then you can see that `(cbrt-iter 1. 64)` returned 1.